# How i remover the retour on line from the sentences

Tags: php

I have the following sentences:

> DEssus
>
> 3 Liasee
>
> Dessous

how can i do function  to ensure that the sentence stays on one line:
Output :

> DEssus 3 Liasse Dessous

Comment: What is the code currently you are using to output the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $sentence);
```

Be careful to use double quotes, otherwise it won't work with PHP for some certainly good reasons.